# "Cannot create a file when that file already exists" when opening configuration editor in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config, iis-8.5

My IIS has multiple sites hosted with the below structure

[image]

I have also encrypted certain sections of the web.config files in `Site2` and `Site3` and also in applications inside the `Site1`. I have used the below command to encrypt config files.

```
aspnet_regiis –pef “section_to_encrypt” “path_of_config_file” –prov “CustomProvider”
```

What I now see after encrypting the config files is whenever I try to open the configuration editor of any application **INSIDE** Site1 from IIS, it crashes with the below error.

[image]

Also, this is occurring ONLY for the applications **inside `Site1`** and NOT for other sites like Site2 and Site3. Can someone explain what exactly happens when I try to open the configuration editor and why iis manager could be throwing the error?

Thank you!

**[Update] :** This error comes only for the sites whose config file has been encrypted.